# Using Elixir/Phoenix, can't create a record with empty fields from web UI due to strict validation with CRUD generated by phoenix.gen.resource

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix 0.10.0 app, I ran

```
mix phoenix.gen.resource Job jobs job_name:string job_url:string company_url:string location:string notes:string
```

following up by adding a `resources` line `router.ex` and running `mix ecto.migrate`.

With these changes, creating a new record from the web interface works fine as long as I fill out all the fields. If I leave a single one of them blank there's an error message saying "Oops, something went wrong!" in the browser.

I'd like to allow the notes to be left blank. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The required fields are listed in the third argument to `cast` in the definition of `changeset` so remove the ones that aren't required there and add them to the list of optional arguments at the end:

```
git diff
diff --git a/web/models/job.ex b/web/models/job.ex
index 2d6303b..323b114 100644
--- a/web/models/job.ex
+++ b/web/models/job.ex
@@ -18,6 +18,6 @@ defmodule JobHunt.Job do
   with no validation performed.
   """
   def changeset(model, params \\ nil) do
-    cast(model, params, ~w(job_url), ~w())
+    cast(model, params, ~w(job_url), ~w(job_name company_url location notes))
   end
 end
```

(Edited.)

Comment: That's it! Also improved error handling is coming on the next release.